Can't get bootstrap dropdown in my header to work after changing pages
Using Ruby on Rails and Boostrap 5.3 to create a site to host my projects and info. I have a header file containing all of my navbar code. After visiting any link from one of the dropdown options, the dropdown button no longer works.
However, when I click on one of the links inside of the navbar, but not found in the dropdown and change pages, everything still works fine (i.e. if I click on "About Me" and go to that page it works but not if I open the dropdown and go to "Yelp Review Manager" or any of the other pages listed as options). Reloading the page also makes the dropdown work again.
Code:
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand">Title</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <%= link_to "Home", root_path, class:"nav-link"%>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <%= link_to "About Me", home_about_path, class:"nav-link" %>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Projects
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <%= link_to "Living Atlas", projects_livingatlas_path, class:"dropdown-item" %>
            <%= link_to "Spreadsheet", projects_spreadsheet_path, class:"dropdown-item" %>
            <%= link_to "Yelp Review Manager", projects_yelp_path, class:"dropdown-item" %>
            <%= link_to "Ext2 File System", projects_ext2_path, class:"dropdown-item" %>
            <%= link_to "Personal Website", projects_website_path, class:"dropdown-item" %>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>


Are there are any console errors?

No errors showing in the console. Having the same problem trying to close accordion dropdowns, as well.

Needed to delete <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'bootstrap', media: 'all' %> and <%= javascript_importmap_tags 'application', 'data-turbo-track': 'reload' %> inside of app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
File after changes:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Flavio Projects</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>
    <%# This is where the two lines causing the issues were found %>

  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'shared/header' %>
    <div class="container">
      <br/>
      <%= yield %>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

